# import theano as CPU(directly trying to open GPU)

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

I am trying to import theano, but it directly import GPU. I want to import theono on CPU.
here is the error when i try to import theano

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lasagne\layers\dnn.py in <module>()
      1 import theano
----> 2 from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn
      3 
      4 from .. import init
      5 from .. import nonlinearities

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\__init__.py in <module>()
     57 # is_nvcc_available called here to initialize global vars in
     58 # nvcc_compiler module
---> 59 nvcc_compiler.is_nvcc_available()
     60 
     61 # Compile cuda_ndarray.cu

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda\nvcc_compiler.py in is_nvcc_available()
     28 
     29     """
---> 30     if not config.cuda.enabled:
     31         return False
     32 

AttributeError: 'SubObj' object has no attribute 'enabled'
```

Comment: `from theano.sandbox.cuda import dnn` requires a gpu.

Comment: thanks for the message,is there any possibility to run on cpu?

Comment: Your script is importing dnn, so it is not possible. Check with the authors if a cpu alternative exists

Comment: there is no reply from author, any other way, like can i change from theano to kears?